# Possible to display worker names in Dask web UI?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am able to add workers to the dask-scheduler and they appear in the web ui, but the workers are listed by their IP addresses, not the names I've given them.

When I create the workers (in a Python script), I do set the name:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client as Dask_Client
from distributed import Worker

dask_client = Dask_Client('192.168.0.162:8786')
loop = IOLoop.current()
t = threading.Thread(target=loop.start, daemon=True)
t.start()
w = Worker('tcp://192.168.0.162:8786', loop=loop, name=socket.gethostname())
w.start()
```

And the worker name does appear when I run print(json.dumps(dask_client.scheduler_info(), sort_keys=True, indent=4)) -- excerpt below:

```
    "tcp://192.168.0.198:39619": {
        "host": "192.168.0.198",
        "id": "alana1",
        "last_seen": 1558707665.9223647,
        "local_directory": "[omitted]",
        "memory_limit": 8243511296,
        "metrics": {
            "cpu": 4.0,
            "executing": 0,
            "in_flight": 0,
            "in_memory": 330,
            "memory": 245129216,
            "num_fds": 26,
            "read_bytes": 3020.000227124918,
            "ready": 0,
            "time": 1558707665.9237077,
            "write_bytes": 3484.3077504469734
        },
        "name": "alana1",
        "ncores": 4,
        "resources": {},
        "services": {
            "bokeh": 37993,
            "nanny": 35817
        },
        "type": "Worker"
```

In the above example, I was hoping the name "alana1" would appear in the Dask web UI instead of what does appear: "tcp://192.168.0.198:39619"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That is possible with changes to the Dask codebase.

*It sounds like you're asking for a feature request.  I recommend raising a github issue.*

Comment: Thank you, @mrocklin.  I added the feature request:  https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4878